# missing_default_values_of_parameter and if i fix this error another error missing_required_argument_ is showing in flutter vscode

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am new to Flutter and am trying to create my own wallpaper app by following some online tutorials. However, I am stuck when trying to create a category page. I don't know how to solve the error I am seeing, which appears to be related to the parameters. I tried adding the  keyword to fix the error, but now the page is showing another error related to the DefaultAppBar. I have been stuck on this issue for hours, and would appreciate any help. Here is the code:

```
import 'package:classico/components/constant.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DefaultAppBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  final String title;
  final Widget child;
  // ignore: prefer_typing_uninitialized_variables
  final action;
  const DefaultAppBar({
    Key? key,
    this.title,
    this.child,
    this.action,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => const Size.fromHeight(56.0);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
      title: Text(title, style: const TextStyle(color: kPrimaryColor)),
      centerTitle: true,
      backgroundColor: kWhiteColor,
      elevation: kRadius,
      automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      iconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: kPrimaryColor),
      leading: child,
      actions: action,
    );
  }
}
```

and after this is after i included

```
import 'package:classico/components/constant.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DefaultAppBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  final String title;
  final Widget child;
  // ignore: prefer_typing_uninitialized_variables
  final action;
  const DefaultAppBar({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
    required this.child,
    this.action,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => const Size.fromHeight(56.0);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
      title: Text(title, style: const TextStyle(color: kPrimaryColor)),
      centerTitle: true,
      backgroundColor: kWhiteColor,
      elevation: kRadius,
      automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      iconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: kPrimaryColor),
      leading: child,
      actions: action,
    );
  }
}
```

now the error is showing in the DefaultAppBar. what can i do now, i'm stuck here for hours.

```
// ignore_for_file: prefer_const_constructors_in_immutables, prefer_const_constructors, prefer_typing_uninitialized_variables

import 'package:classico/components/constant.dart';
import 'package:classico/components/default_app_bar.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CategoryPage extends StatefulWidget {
  CategoryPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CategoryPage> createState() => _CategoryPage();
}

class _CategoryPage extends State<CategoryPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: kWhiteColor,
      appBar: DefaultAppBar(
        title: "Category",
      ),

      ///body: CategoryView(),
    );
  }
}

class CategoryView extends StatelessWidget {
  final int column, items;
  final Widget child;
  final Color color;
  final double ratio, height, width;
  final direction, itemBuilder;
  const CategoryView({
    super.key,
    required this.column,
    required this.items,
    required this.child,
    required this.color,
    required this.ratio,
    required this.height,
    required this.width,
    this.direction,
    this.itemBuilder,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: height,
      width: width,
      color: color,
      child: GridView.builder(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(kLess),
          scrollDirection: direction,
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisCount: column,
              childAspectRatio: ratio,
              mainAxisSpacing: 0,
              crossAxisSpacing: 0),
          itemCount: items,
          itemBuilder: itemBuilder),
    );
  }
}
```